# use tipbox from awesomebox with items inside doesn't englobed all my text

Tags: fontawesome5

here's my code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{awesomebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tipbox}
L’utilisation de formes trigonométriques donne facilement les expressions des racines carrées d’un nombre complexe non nul quelconque mais on a parfois besoin d’exprimer une racine de $z$ sous forme algébrique, i.e. sans utilisation de ligne trigonométrique. On a vu ci-dessus comment faire lorsque $z \in \mathbb{R}$. Supposons donc $z \notin \mathbb{R}$ et prenons $z = x + iy$ avec $x \in \mathbb{R}$ et $y \in \mathbb{R^*}$. Soit $Z = X + i Y$ avec $(X, Y ) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ tel que $Z^2 = z$.

\begin{itemize}
    \item On en déduit :
    \begin{itemize}
        \item par égalité des parties réelles, $X^2 - Y^2 = x$; \hfill (i)
        \item par égalité des modules, $X^2 + Y^2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$; \hfill (ii)
        \item par égalité des parties imaginaires, $2XY = y$; \hfill (iii) \\ 
        (comme $y \neq 0$, cela entraîne $X \neq 0$ et $Y \neq 0$). \\
        Par somme et différence de (i) et (ii), on obtient $X^2$ et $Y^2$, et donc $X$ et $Y$ au signe près, soit quatre possibilités puisque $X \neq 0$ et $Y \neq 0$.
    \end{itemize}
    \item D’après (iii) le produit $XY$ est du signe de $y$ et il existe donc seulement deux couples $(X, Y )$ vérifiant ces trois conditions, couples que l’on peut alors exprimer en fonction de $x$ et de $y$.
    \item Bien que n’utilisant que des conditions nécessaires (implications), le raisonnement précédent donne toutes les racines de $z$ puisqu’il en donne au plus deux et que l’on sait qu’il en existe exactement deux.
\end{itemize}
\end{tipbox}

\end{document}
```

Which give me

[image]

How can I embedded all my text in the tipbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using   `\tipbox{<text>}`  and `\newline` instead of `\\`

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{awesomebox}

\begin{document}
    
        \tipbox{%changed<<<<<<<<<<<
            L’utilisation de formes trigonométriques donne facilement les expressions des racines carrées d’un nombre complexe non nul quelconque mais on a parfois besoin d’exprimer une racine de $z$ sous forme algébrique, i.e. sans utilisation de ligne trigonométrique. On a vu ci-dessus comment faire lorsque $z \in \mathbb{R}$. Supposons donc $z \notin \mathbb{R}$ et prenons $z = x + iy$ avec $x \in \mathbb{R}$ et $y \in \mathbb{R^*}$. Soit $Z = X + i Y$ avec $(X, Y ) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ tel que $Z^2 = z$.
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \item On en déduit :
            \begin{itemize}
                \item par égalité des parties réelles, $X^2 - Y^2 = x$; \hfill (i)
                \item par égalité des modules, $X^2 + Y^2 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$; \hfill (ii)
                \item par égalité des parties imaginaires, $2XY = y$; \hfill (iii) \newline %changed<<<<<<<<<<<
                (comme $y \neq 0$, cela entraîne $X \neq 0$ et $Y \neq 0$). \newline %changed<<<<<<<<<<<
                Par somme et différence de (i) et (ii), on obtient $X^2$ et $Y^2$, et donc $X$ et $Y$ au signe près, soit quatre possibilités puisque $X \neq 0$ et $Y \neq 0$.
            \end{itemize}
            \item D’après (iii) le produit $XY$ est du signe de $y$ et il existe donc seulement deux couples $(X, Y )$ vérifiant ces trois conditions, couples que l’on peut alors exprimer en fonction de $x$ et de $y$.
            \item Bien que n’utilisant que des conditions nécessaires (implications), le raisonnement précédent donne toutes les racines de $z$ puisqu’il en donne au plus deux et que l’on sait qu’il en existe exactement deux.
        \end{itemize}
    }
    
\end{document}
```